# Azure Service Bus Redundancy for Data Center Outages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a question on service bus. Whenever we create a service bus namespace it will ask for a region, so is there redundancy across different regions for sb?

Also, how about applications spanning in different regions? Can we do some intelligent load balancing like we can do for web apps using Traffic manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I've not heard of anyone using traffic manager, but this I'm not sure of. My instinct is to say no...

Second, there is good documentation on handling service bus outages:
**[Best Practices for Insulating Service Bus Applications Against Service Bus Outages and Disasters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554355.aspx)**

This article talks about partitioning queues to have multiple message stores, protecting against datacenter outages, and more.

Bottom line create two namespaces (primary/secondary) in different regions, then create an entity in both.